# What makes Avada Kedavra "Unforgivable"?

Tags: harry-potter

In the Harry Potter universe, Avada Kedavra, the Killing Curse, is classified as "Unforgivable". The use of it on a fellow human being is enough to earn a life sentence in Azkaban.

There are other ways of killing someone with spells in Harry Potter, however. For example, when Molly Weasley is dueling Bellatrix in the final battle, it is depicted (at least in the film) that the spell Molly uses seems to cause Bellatrix to crumble away, in the same style as what happens as a result of Thanos' snap in *Avengers: Infinity War*). I can't imagine this has earned Molly a life sentence for using magic to kill.

Why is Avada Kevadra considered "Unforgivable" and not the other spells that are capable of killing?

Comment: Note that Molly killing Bellatrix occurred during a literal war, at a time when the central wizarding government had collapsed. Avada Kedavra or not, the circumstances were different at that precise moment.

Comment: I don't recall, but I _think_ it was because AK is unblockable as well.

Comment: @Möoz so essentially sportsman conduct kill if needed but you've got to give your opponent a chance